# Javascript - get location.pathname + location.search - not taking all parts

Tags: javascript, html

I am writing js function which takes the actual `location.pathname + location.seach`, so that the user can come back to search result page if he hits `back` button.

example url: `http://127.0.0.1:8000/search_for_book/?titel=&autor=doniyor#`

```
function select_book(bookid){
  var backurl = String(window.location.pathname+window.location.search);
  //alert(backurl); //<---- this is giving the correct full path
  window.location = 'selected/?book_id=' + bookid + '&back=' + backurl;
}
```

but in the last line, function is appending only till `?titel=` and cuts off the rest. the new url is becoming this:

```
http://127.0.0.1:8000/search_for_book/selected/?book_id=10&back=/search_for_book/?titel=
```

why is this? i need full location.pathname with full location.search.

any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> but in the last line, function is appending only till ?titel= and cuts off the rest.

No, it doesn’t. Alerting/logging the string value that you’re assigning to window.location would have shown you that. (And btw., `window.location.href` is the correct way to update the location. `location` itself is an object, not a property – only the browsers’ error tolerance lets you do it this way. So use `window.location.href = …` instead.)

It’s going wrong, because `&` in a URL separates parameters from each other. So the value of your parameter `back` ends after the `&`, and then comes a *new* parameter `autor` – because you neglected to URL-encode the parameter value properly.

Use `encodeURIComponent` on the value, before adding it into the string.